# Can you set a specific colour for whole QTableWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt, qtablewidget

Ok so we can set a specific background color for a cell that contains data:

```
self.Table.item(0,i).setBackground(QColor(255,128,128))
```

Is it possible to set the whole table at initiation or during operations to a specific color? At initiation it doesn't contain any data so the cells are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all cells to have that background color then you can use a delegate:

```py
class Delegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        if not index.data(Qt.BackgroundRole):
            option.backgroundBrush = QBrush(QColor(255, 128, 128))
```

```
delegate = Delegate(self.Table)
self.Table.setItemDelegate(delegate)
```

Comment: Gives the solution to my question but a new problem arises: the cell colour can't be overwritten now. How do I solve that? So at initiation it has the colour (255, 128, 128) but when some if statement occurs in the program it needs to change to (150,150,150).

Comment: Yup that's the one. I have one more small question: do you know how to evaluate variables as QColors: vGray = (150,150,150). I can't put Gray after QBrush(QColor(255, 128, 128)) like this QBrush(QColor(vGray))

Comment: @wecandothis use `QBrush(QColor(*vGray)) `

Comment: @wecandothis read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments

Comment: Hey, can you take a look at my new question regarding pyqt? Is it possible, in the spirit of your answer here, to assign specific colours to specific columns?